# How do you apply multiple click event listeners to images in android

Tags: android, listener

First time Android Studio user, been working on a mini program where 5 images are displayed on the screen. When the user clicks each image the user is redirected to another activity that displays more information. So far I've gotten one image to work my hardin_valley image.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewHardin);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, hardin_valley.class));
        }
    });
}
```

The question I have is I also have blonty_county, division_street and magnolia images I want to redirect to new activities when the user clicks. How would I go about creating individual listeners. Or, what would be the best approach, Thank You

Comment: are you having 5 different imageview for your 5 different images?

Comment: so implements OnClickListener to you class and in `OnClik` method use`switch` case to perform action according to your imageview id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach if u have multiple Listeners in your activity is to just add  the `android:onClick="clickHandler"` Tag in your XML to every Image View, then back at your java class you can do this:

```
public void clickHandler(View v)
{
    if(v == R.id.imageViewHardin)
       //do something

     else if(v == R.id.imageViewBlueCounty)
       //do something else

}
```

Comment: Yeah you right, didn't even think about doing a loop for listeners. I started to declare each image, then I read your comment and realized my way would be pointless additional code. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use `switch-case` at `onClick` to which view is clicked

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //-your all image views to link layout-//
    ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    im.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    // -- find here id of your all 5 image view 
    case R.id.image:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }   
}
```